# Background image in a text DIV

Tags: css, html, background-image

I have a simple container with some text. I am trying to put a background image that is not repeated, exactly in the center behind the text, but my code doesn work. This here is a reference: http://www.danielhopwood.com/#about

My code is this for the text container:

```
.main-descr {
background: url(img/cnp_bg.png) no-repeat center;
            }
```

but the image(cnp3.png) doesnt show up, click here: http://www.mysecretathens.gr/CNP/about.html

Why is that and what can I do? Using `background-image` makes no difference..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is getting a 404 for that image.  The url should be relative to the CSS.

```
background: url(../img/cnp3.png);
```

Notice the ../

Then you should be able to do:

```
background: url(../img/cnp3.png) no-repeat center center;
```